# Moving table from under picture next to it

Tags: html, css, alignment, element

I've tried to find the issue, but just could not, as it seems a bit complicated.

As you can see in the snippet, the first table declares the weight of the div together with the img and if the second table next to the image, has bigger weight then the first one, then it just moves under. I would like to know a "clean" solution, whether using float like this is wrong, etc., as I could just set a bigger static weight of the first table and that would solve the entire problem. (I just changed the text "profession:" to "prof:", as it reduces the table weight and causes the problem to appear)

```css
#gameContainer {
 margin-top: 20px;
}

#character {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 18px;
}

#gameTitle {
 font-family: GameFont;
 font-size: 70px;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
 text-align: center;
}

#attributes td {
 padding-left: 10px;
}

#explore {
 margin-top: 45px;
 text-align: center;
}

.bttn:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
}

.bttn {
 box-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px 3px black;
 width: 24px;
}

#lvl {
 margin-top: 30px;
}
#start {
 margin-top: 45px;
}

#Log {
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-right: 5%;
}

#point {
 margin-top: 45px;
 font-size: 21px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#lvl {
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#exp {
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 font-size: 16px;
}

#neededExp {
 margin-top: 5px;
 font-size: 16px;
}

#gold {
 margin-top: 30px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#mainAttributes {
 text-align: left;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 24px;
 padding-bottom: 45px;
}

#attributes{f
 text-align: left;
 font-size: 20px;
 display: inline-block;
}

.logEntries {
 display: none;
}

.choiceBtn {
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-top: 3%;
}

.death {
 color: red;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.boldUp {
 font-weight: bold;
}

.optionMenuBtn {
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-top: 3%;
}

#optionMenu {
 text-align: center;
 display: none;
}

.optionMenuBtn:nth-child(1) {
 margin-left: 0px;
}

#actionMenu {
 text-align: center;
}

.actionMenuBtn {
 margin-left: 5%;
}

.actionMenuBtn:nth-child(1) {
 margin-left: 0px;
}

.choiceBtn:nth-child(1) {
 margin-left: 0px;
}

.playerAttack {
 text-align:left;
}

.enemyAttack {
 text-align: right;
}

#battleLog {
 margin-left: 35%;
 margin-right: 35%;
 margin-top: 10%;
 text-align: center;
}

#battleLog h1 {
 font-size: 50px;
 margin-bottom: 10%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="gameContainer">
  <h1 id="gameTitle">Your character</h1>
  <div id="character">
   <div id="attributes">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/51/0d/99/510d992e8ef64fe523a025208fbf8f5e--fantasy-images-elf.jpg" style="width: 260px; margin-right: 20px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black; float: left;"> 
    <table id="mainAttributes">
     <tr>
      <td>Name:</td>
      <td><span id="name"></span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Race:</td>
      <td><span id="race"></span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Prof:</td>
      <td><span id ="profession"></span></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td><span>Strength:</span></td>
      <td><span id="strength"></span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><span>Endurance:</span></td>
      <td><span id="endurance"></span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><span>Dexterity:</span></td>
      <td><span id="dexterity"></span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><span>Intelligence:</span></td>
      <td><span id="intelligence"></span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><span>Charism:</span></td>
      <td><span id="charism"></span></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start by removing the `display:inline-block;` from `#attributes` and also removing the `text-align:center;` from `#character`.  This way you have the default display settings for the table.  No extra properties to mess with just yet.

```css
#gameContainer {
 margin-top: 20px;
}

#character {
 font-size: 18px;
}

#gameTitle {
 font-family: GameFont;
 font-size: 70px;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
 text-align: center;
}

#attributes td {
 padding-left: 10px;
}

#explore {
 margin-top: 45px;
 text-align: center;
}

.bttn:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
}

.bttn {
 box-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px 3px black;
 width: 24px;
}

#lvl {
 margin-top: 30px;
}
#start {
 margin-top: 45px;
}

#Log {
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-right: 5%;
}

#point {
 margin-top: 45px;
 font-size: 21px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#lvl {
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#exp {
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 font-size: 16px;
}

#neededExp {
 margin-top: 5px;
 font-size: 16px;
}

#gold {
 margin-top: 30px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#mainAttributes {
 text-align: left;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 24px;
 padding-bottom: 45px;
}

#attributes{
 text-align: left;
 font-size: 20px;
}

.logEntries {
 display: none;
}

.choiceBtn {
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-top: 3%;
}

.death {
 color: red;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.boldUp {
 font-weight: bold;
}

.optionMenuBtn {
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-top: 3%;
}

#optionMenu {
 text-align: center;
 display: none;
}

.optionMenuBtn:nth-child(1) {
 margin-left: 0px;
}

#actionMenu {
 text-align: center;
}

.actionMenuBtn {
 margin-left: 5%;
}

.actionMenuBtn:nth-child(1) {
 margin-left: 0px;
}

.choiceBtn:nth-child(1) {
 margin-left: 0px;
}

.playerAttack {
 text-align:left;
}

.enemyAttack {
 text-align: right;
}

#battleLog {
 margin-left: 35%;
 margin-right: 35%;
 margin-top: 10%;
 text-align: center;
}

#battleLog h1 {
 font-size: 50px;
 margin-bottom: 10%;
}
```

```html
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="gameContainer">
  <h1 id="gameTitle">Your character</h1>
  <div id="character">
   <div id="attributes">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/51/0d/99/510d992e8ef64fe523a025208fbf8f5e--fantasy-images-elf.jpg" style="width: 260px; margin-right: 20px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black; float: left;"> 
    <table id="mainAttributes">
     <tr>
      <td>Name:</td>
      <td><span id="name">assssssssssssssss</span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Race:</td>
      <td><span id="race">asdasdsaddsasad</span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Profession:</td>
      <td><span id ="profession">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><span>Strength:</span></td>
      <td><span id="strength">asdadsdasfsdgfshgdh</span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><span>Endurance:</span></td>
      <td><span id="endurance"></span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><span>Dexterity:</span></td>
      <td><span id="dexterity"></span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><span>Intelligence:</span></td>
      <td><span id="intelligence"></span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><span>Charism:</span></td>
      <td><span id="charism"></span></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your situation is with the page, but increase the "attributes" width to something like 500px or more and floating the table to right would work. Since this seems very basic, I would suggest this answer but it's not something I would usually recommend. This is a bad practice but it does work.

I always recommend making a proper base style sheet or using a framework like bootstrap helps designing websites properly.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but why did you create 2 tables?
what about this solution?

```css
#gameContainer {
 margin-top: 20px;
}

#character {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 18px;
}

#gameTitle {
 font-family: GameFont;
 font-size: 70px;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
 text-align: center;
}

#attributes td {
 padding-left: 10px;
}

#explore {
 margin-top: 45px;
 text-align: center;
}

.bttn:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
}

.bttn {
 box-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px 3px black;
 width: 24px;
}

#lvl {
 margin-top: 30px;
}
#start {
 margin-top: 45px;
}

#Log {
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-right: 5%;
}

#point {
 margin-top: 45px;
 font-size: 21px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#lvl {
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#exp {
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 font-size: 16px;
}

#neededExp {
 margin-top: 5px;
 font-size: 16px;
}

#gold {
 margin-top: 30px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#mainAttributes {
 text-align: left;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 24px;
 padding-bottom: 45px;
}

#attributes{
 text-align: left;
 font-size: 20px;
 display: inline-block;
}

.logEntries {
 display: none;
}

.choiceBtn {
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-top: 3%;
}

.death {
 color: red;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.boldUp {
 font-weight: bold;
}

.optionMenuBtn {
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-top: 3%;
}

#optionMenu {
 text-align: center;
 display: none;
}

.optionMenuBtn:nth-child(1) {
 margin-left: 0px;
}

#actionMenu {
 text-align: center;
}

.actionMenuBtn {
 margin-left: 5%;
}

.actionMenuBtn:nth-child(1) {
 margin-left: 0px;
}

.choiceBtn:nth-child(1) {
 margin-left: 0px;
}

.playerAttack {
 text-align:left;
}

.enemyAttack {
 text-align: right;
}

#battleLog {
 margin-left: 35%;
 margin-right: 35%;
 margin-top: 10%;
 text-align: center;
}

#battleLog h1 {
 font-size: 50px;
 margin-bottom: 10%;
}
```

```html
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="gameContainer">
  <h1 id="gameTitle">Your character</h1>
  <div id="character">
   <div id="attributes">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/51/0d/99/510d992e8ef64fe523a025208fbf8f5e--fantasy-images-elf.jpg" style="width: 260px; margin-right: 20px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black; float: left;"> 
    <table id="mainAttributes">
     <tr>
      <td>Name:</td>
      <td><span id="name">assssssssssssssss</span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Race:</td>
      <td><span id="race">asdasdsaddsasad</span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Profession:</td>
      <td><span id ="profession">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><span>Strength:</span></td>
      <td><span id="strength">asdadsdasfsdgfshgdh</span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><span>Endurance:</span></td>
      <td><span id="endurance"></span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><span>Dexterity:</span></td>
      <td><span id="dexterity"></span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><span>Intelligence:</span></td>
      <td><span id="intelligence"></span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><span>Charism:</span></td>
      <td><span id="charism"></span></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </div>
```

Using just 1 table, anyway I suggest you to use display:flex . Anyway here in my code just resize dinamically that image and it works

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but why did you create 2 tables?
what about this solution?

```css
#gameContainer {
 margin-top: 20px;
}

#character {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 18px;
}

#gameTitle {
 font-family: GameFont;
 font-size: 70px;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
 text-align: center;
}

#attributes td {
 padding-left: 10px;
}

#explore {
 margin-top: 45px;
 text-align: center;
}

.bttn:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
}

.bttn {
 box-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px 3px black;
 width: 24px;
}

#lvl {
 margin-top: 30px;
}
#start {
 margin-top: 45px;
}

#Log {
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-right: 5%;
}

#point {
 margin-top: 45px;
 font-size: 21px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#lvl {
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#exp {
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 font-size: 16px;
}

#neededExp {
 margin-top: 5px;
 font-size: 16px;
}

#gold {
 margin-top: 30px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#mainAttributes {
 text-align: left;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 24px;
 padding-bottom: 45px;
  width:40%!important
}

#attributes{
 text-align: left;
 font-size: 20px;
 display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
img{
  display: block;
  max-height:500px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 20px; 
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black; float: left;
}
.logEntries {
 display: none;
}

.choiceBtn {
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-top: 3%;
}

.death {
 color: red;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.boldUp {
 font-weight: bold;
}

.optionMenuBtn {
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-top: 3%;
}

#optionMenu {
 text-align: center;
 display: none;
}

.optionMenuBtn:nth-child(1) {
 margin-left: 0px;
}

#actionMenu {
 text-align: center;
}

.actionMenuBtn {
 margin-left: 5%;
}

.actionMenuBtn:nth-child(1) {
 margin-left: 0px;
}

.choiceBtn:nth-child(1) {
 margin-left: 0px;
}

.playerAttack {
 text-align:left;
}

.enemyAttack {
 text-align: right;
}

#battleLog {
 margin-left: 35%;
 margin-right: 35%;
 margin-top: 10%;
 text-align: center;
}

#battleLog h1 {
 font-size: 50px;
 margin-bottom: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div id="gameContainer">
  <h1 id="gameTitle">Your character</h1>
  <div id="character">
   <div id="attributes">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/51/0d/99/510d992e8ef64fe523a025208fbf8f5e--fantasy-images-elf.jpg"> 
    <table id="mainAttributes">
     <tr>
      <td>Name:</td>
      <td><span id="name">assssssssssssssss</span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Race:</td>
      <td><span id="race">asdasdsaddsasad</span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Profession:</td>
      <td><span id ="profession">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><span>Strength:</span></td>
      <td><span id="strength">asdadsdasfsdgfshgdh</span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><span>Endurance:</span></td>
      <td><span id="endurance"></span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><span>Dexterity:</span></td>
      <td><span id="dexterity"></span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><span>Intelligence:</span></td>
      <td><span id="intelligence"></span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><span>Charism:</span></td>
      <td><span id="charism"></span></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </div>
```

Using just 1 table, anyway I suggest you to use display:flex .